# Very slow INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO on postgres

Tags: python, database, postgresql, query-optimization, psycopg2

I've been banging my head against the wall for days with this one. I have a PostgreSQL database on a Hetzner VPS CPX51 (https://www.hetzner.com/cloud). The database main table is around 5M rows with an average width of 116. Here is the database table declaration in Python and its definition in Postgres:

```py
class Record(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'records'

    hash      = Column(String, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    domain    = Column(String)
    content     = Column(String)

    status1_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('record_status_one.id'))

    status2_id     = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('record_status_two.id'))
    status3_id   = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('record_status_three.id'))

    timestamp = Column(DateTime, default=func.now())

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.id}:{self.domain}'

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for property, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, property, value)
```

```
domains=# \d records
                           Table "public.records"
   Column    |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 hash        | character varying           |           | not null | 
 domain      | character varying           |           |          | 
 content     | character varying           |           |          | 
 status1_id  | integer                     |           |          | 
 status2_id  | integer                     |           |          | 
 status3_id  | integer                     |           |          | 
 timestamp   | timestamp without time zone |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "records_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (hash) CLUSTER
    "idx_btree" btree (domain)
    "idx_gin_records_domains" gin (domain gin_trgm_ops)
    "idx_records_gin" gin (content gin_trgm_ops)
    "idx_status_id" btree (status1_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "records_status_one_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (status1_id) REFERENCES status_one(id)
    "records_status_two_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (status2_id) REFERENCES status_two(id)
    "records_status_three_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (status3_id) REFERENCES status_three(id)
```

I am trying to keep data up to date via upserts, so that if there is a conflict on the hash column I update the timestamp column. I have followed all the approaches mentioned in https://hakibenita.com/fast-load-data-python-postgresql and eventually ended seeing that even the last one, which is a `COPY FROM` to an unlogged table and then a select, doesn't work. I keep getting times of around 5 minutes for 1M inserts, which I think is quite slow.

Here is the approach using `psycopg2`:

```py
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute(
f"""
CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE {random_name} (LIKE records) WITH (autovacuum_enabled=false)
"""
)
cur.copy_from(records, random_name, sep='|')
cur.execute(
f"""
explain (analyze,verbose,costs,buffers,summary) INSERT INTO records(hash, domain, content, status1_id, status2_id, status3_id, timestamp)
SELECT * FROM {random_name}
ON CONFLICT (hash) DO UPDATE SET timestamp = now()
"""
)
analyze_fetched = cur.fetchall()
log(analyze_fetched)

cur.execute(f'DROP TABLE {random_name}')
conn.commit()
```

And the output of `analyze_fetched` indicates that most of the time is spent of inserting to the `records` table, if I understand correctly. I have tried with batches of 250k (~ 45 seconds) and of 50k (~ 10 seconds).

```
Insert on public.records  (cost=0.00..8035.56 rows=288456 width=116) (actual time=39466.104..39466.105 rows=0 loops=1)
  Conflict Resolution: UPDATE
  Conflict Arbiter Indexes: records_pkey
  Tuples Inserted: 250001
  Conflicting Tuples: 0
  Buffers: shared hit=7786720 read=2218435 dirtied=1195808 written=1019289
  ->  Seq Scan on public.yqhex  (cost=0.00..8035.56 rows=288456 width=116) (actual time=0.034..97.849 rows=250001 loops=1)
        Output: yqhex.hash, yqhex.domain, yqhex.content, yqhex.status1_id, yqhex.status2_id, yqhex.status3_id, yqhex."timestamp"
        Buffers: shared read=5151 written=1623
Planning Time: 0.863 ms
Trigger RI_ConstraintTrigger_c_133368 for constraint records_status_one_id_fkey: time=2002.606 calls=250001
Trigger RI_ConstraintTrigger_c_133373 for constraint records_status_two_id_fkey: time=1469.651 calls=250001
Trigger RI_ConstraintTrigger_c_133378 for constraint records_status_three_id_fkey: time=1470.330 calls=250001
Execution Time: 44465.493 ms
```

At the beginning I thought this could be associated with the VPS disk latency but checking with `ioping` it seems that write operations are fine:

```
root@ubuntu-32gb-hel1-1 ~ # ioping -q -c 10 -s 8k -W .

--- . (ext4 /dev/sda1) ioping statistics ---
9 requests completed in 8.01 ms, 72 KiB written, 1.12 k iops, 8.78 MiB/s
generated 10 requests in 9.00 s, 80 KiB, 1 iops, 8.89 KiB/s
min/avg/max/mdev = 350.1 us / 890.2 us / 1.60 ms / 431.1 us
```

I wonder if this could be due to the foreign keys but I've read that the overhead shouldn't be that big. I've also thought maybe it was storing all the timestamps but haven't managed to find anything on it either. I'm at a loss and I don't know what else to try, so I would appreciate some help! Please let me know if some data I haven't included would be useful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the table definition and triggers ?

Comment: Updated the question! There are no triggers in the table.

Comment: Most likely limit IO because this query has to write the data and maintain 5 different indexes, resulting in almost 8GB of writes. Besides all the reads it has to do

Comment: maybe not on this table, but what "Trigger RI_ConstraintTrigger_c_133368" means ?

Comment: I think @FrankHeikens is right, dropping all indexes reduces 250k down to ~8s. In my case that would be acceptable, but I'm curious, would that still be slow? So I'm guessing I'll need to make a tradeoff between insert speed and selects speed if I choose to use an index...

Comment: ioping doesn't look fine to me.  1019289 written / 1.12 k iops = 910s.  Since you are getting 910 seconds worth of work done in 44 seconds, that is astonishingly good compared to what ioping would lead one to expect.

Comment: Interestingly the top Cloud VPS indeed outperforms one of the AX servers according to ioping, contrary to what one would expect.

Comment: Now that I add concurrency (10 servers at the same time doing operations), inserts are taking each time longer, reaching a point where 250k inserts take 2 minutes. Why could this be?